# Applying K-Means to HOG-Descriptors

Tags: computer-vision, dlib

I've extracted a HOG-Descriptors using dlib and stored them in an array of two dimensional arrays. Now, I want to cluster the descriptors using K-Means.

How would one perform such clustering? I can think of two ways to implement it:

1. Performing the clustering line-wise. Hence, for any two dimensional array separately.
2. Performing the clustering for all lines at once.

Comment: Sounds like your question already contains the answer.

Comment: Is there only one right answer?

Comment: No, this is more of a research question, not a coding one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dlib contains a program, imglab (in the tools/imglab folder) that has a --cluster option.  This option does k-means clustering on HOG images.  It does it using an angular distance metric which is particularly effective for clustering HOG vectors.  Much more so than the usual Euclidean k-means.

So I would recommend using an angular distance metric.  You can refer to the above tool/dlib for the specifics.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to create the histograms for the HOG descriptors from the centroids? I saw that you use nearest_center() to get the nearest center for an image patch but how to get a distribution histogram of center frequencies?